# TextView, EditText and Java regex

Tags: java, android, regex

My button should set text on TextView from editText, when it contains 3 chars.

I used Java pattern, but likely not correctly, because nothing happens.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Pattern Pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\w(3).*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(et1.getText().toString());
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            tv1.setText(et1.getText().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a syntax issue because `(3)` will try to match `3` not the three characters, 
`.*\\w(3).*`  will match anything then a word character then digit `3` then anything.

It should be `.*\\w{3}.*` where `{}` is used to define range and `()` is used to define capturing groups.

Although for characters it should be `.*[a-zA-Z]{3}.*` because `\\w` also match digits and `_`.

For digits use : `.*[a-zA-Z\d]{3}.*`

Comment: yes, I want also digits, but no special characters like "_", so i should put .*[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}.* ?

Comment: @androidmanifest3 yes , you got it right or you can use `.*[a-zA-Z\d]{3}.*`